# Анимация в обратном порядке

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, css-animation

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии по блоку анимация выполнялась в одну сторону, а при нажатии на абзац — в другую сторону (в обратном порядке, как переход)?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').click(function() {
    $('div').toggleClass('a1').removeClass('a2');
  });
  $('p').click(function() {
    $('div').toggleClass('a2').removeClass('a1');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}
.a1 {
  animation: vras 3s forwards;
}
.a2 {
  animation: vras 3s alternate-reverse forwards;
}
@keyframes vras {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  33% {
    left: 85%;
  }
  66% {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
<p>123</p>
```

Comment: При клике на `p` чёрный блок должен плавно двигаться так же в обратном направлении?

Comment: @Yuri Да, именно над этим тружусь.

Comment: Каких переходов?

Comment: @Yuri без переходов в смысле без применения transition

Comment: PeGaS, я попробую найти ответ на эту тайну :)

Comment: Несколько переформулировал ваш вопрос, упростил формулировку, надеюсь что правильно вас понял. Если вдруг исказил смысл — откатывайте. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте вторую анимацию с обратным движением. Я не знаю точно почему, но нельзя применять одну анимацию туда и обратно к одному элементу

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div').click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('a1')){
        $(this).addClass('a2').removeClass('a1');
      }else{
        $(this).addClass('a1').removeClass('a2');
      };
   });
});
```

```css
div {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: black;
   position: relative;
}

.a1 {
   animation: vras1 3s forwards; 
}

.a2 {
   animation: vras2 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes vras1 {
   from {
      left: 0;
   }
   33% {
      left: 85%;
   }
   66% {
      left: 0;
   }
   to {
      left: 500px;
   }
}
@keyframes vras2 {
   from {
      left: 500px;
   }
   33% {
      left: 0;
   }
   66% {
      left: 85%;
   }
   to{
      left: 0;
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Понятно спасибо

Comment: Вот я к [тому же выводу](https://jsfiddle.net/52qpka10/) пришел. Разве что ещё замена `toggleClass` на `addClass`, по-моему, на пользу идёт коду в целом, но это уже смотря что автору надо.

Comment: @Regent Вы правы, так более корректно. Вообще в идеале, если бы класс сменялся на a1 и a2 при нажатии только на блок. Я по незнанию   поставил добавление класса a2 на абзац.

Comment: @PeGaS, могу изменить ответ и показать, как сделать только на блок

Comment: @Yuri Да, хорошо

Comment: @PeGaS, изменил, смотри