# Анимация в обратном направлении при повторном клике

Tags: javascript, анимация, frontend, css-animation

Мне нужно сделать такую анимацию, где при клике на элемент стили меняются через несколько состояний, а при повторном клике анимация воспроизводится в обратном направлении.

К примеру, в начальном состоянии блок имеет высоту 50px и ширину 300px. Во втором состоянии у него ширина, допустим, удваивается. И в третьем, последнем - удваивается высота. То есть ширина и высота не одновременно изменяются сразу к третьему состоянию, а в определённой строгой последовательности.

Но и это ещё не всё. Мне нужно, чтобы все эти состояния были пройдены в обратном порядке. В нашем случае блок с шириной 600px и высотой 100px из третьего состояния переходит ко второму, где у него высота сокращается к 50px, а уже потом (только потом) сокращается и высота к 300px.

Пробовал реализовать с помощью CSS-анимации (animation). Но у меня не получилось воспроизводить анимацию в обратном порядке при повторном клике. Изменение стилей запускал с помощью добавления/удаления класса (то есть с помощью тумблера) к элементу по клику левой клавишей мышки.

Как выполнить такую анимацию? С/без JS/JQ - всё равно. Абы работало.

Или вот этот вариант ([Анимация в обратном порядке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612735/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5)), где задаётся две отдельные анимации для начального и конечного состояния - единственный приемлемый?